# Select next badge, tag badge not showing

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

There is a tag [biztalk-2013r2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk-2013r2) in which I have [answered multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2571021%20%5Bbiztalk-2013r2%5D) which have both been checked as the answer and up-voted for.  However it does not appear in the 'Select your next badge' option in my profile.  Is there a reason that it doesn't show (e.g. I was the one that created the tag) or is it a bug?

[image: Select your next badge]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A tag must appear in at least [100 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68395) before you can earn a tag badge in it. At the moment, there are only [75 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk-2013r2) tagged with [biztalk-2013r2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/biztalk-2013r2). That's *probably* why it doesn't appear between the next tag badges.

Comment: I don't get any *tag* badges showing up, either for subjects where I have them, e.g. vb.net, or don't have them. Are they even eligible for "Select your next badge"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton you need to click the Settings wheel in the Reputation box, not the Badges box.

Comment: It now has over 100 questions (101) and yes, it is now showing up  in the 'Select your next badge' option for me.